# Implementing a type-safe class hierarchy w/ a nullable value

Tags: kotlin

I (often) have a resource with two states, pre-created and post-created, where both states have the same fields except for an `id` field. `id` is null in the pre-created state and non-null in the post-created state.

I would like to define and use this resource in a clean and type-safe way.

It's common to represent this ID field as a nullable, which handles both scenarios with minimal boilerplate in the class definition. The problem is that it creates a lot of boilerplate in the business logic because you can't assert whether a resource is pre-created or post-created by looking at its type.

Here is an example of the nullable approach:

`data class Resource(val id: String?, val property: String)`

This is simple to define, but not as simple to handle with due to lack of compile-time guarantees.

Here's an example of a more type-safe approach:

```
sealed class Resource(val property: String) {
  class WithoutID(property: String): Resource(property)
  class WithID(val id: String, property: String): Resource(property)
}
```

This allows me to pass around `Resource.WithID` and `Resource.WithoutID`, which have all the same fields and methods, except for `id`.

One inconvenience with this type-safe approach is that the resource definition code gets quite bloated when you have many `property` fields. This bloating makes the code harder to read.

I'm wondering if there's an alternative approach with less boilerplate, or if Kotlin has any features that make this kind of thing simpler.

Answer (score 1):

What about defining

```
sealed class MayHaveId<T> { abstract val record: T }
class WithId<T>(val id: String, override val record: T): MayHaveId<T>()
class WithoutId<T>(override val record: T): MayHaveId<T>()

class Resource(val property: String)
// and other similar types
```

and using `WithId<Resource>` and `WithoutId<Resource>`? In Scala you could add an implicit conversion from `MayHaveId<T>` to `T`, but not in Kotlin, alas, nor can you write `: T by record`. Still should be clean enough to use.

Comment: this is interesting, and useful because it can be applied to any T.

Comment: my main problem with this is that it's not as data-centric. `id` and `record` are properties of `MayHaveId`, so in practice, you would have to (un/)pack and (de/)serialize them separately. in my original implementation, `id` and `property` are direct attributes of the resource itself, and it is a single object.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to get into composition relying on `properties` inside interfaces.

```
interface Resource {
    val property: String
}

interface WithId : Resource {
    val id: Int
}

interface WithOtherField : Resource {
    val otherField: Any
}


class WithoutIdImpl(override val property: String) : Resource
class WithIdImpl(override val id: Int, override val property: String) : WithId
class WithIdAndOtherField(
        override val id: Int,
        override val otherField: Any,
        override val property: String) : WithId, WithOtherField
```

I didn't get from your example, how you're going to switch between two states of `Resource`. So probably there is a gap to overcome.
Probably, Smart casts will allow to switch states.

Comment: it's a common pattern when creating a resource, either from a client-server protocol or from a server-db protocol. e.g. the client sends a POST request w/ a resource w/o ID, then the same resource is returned with the ID.